# How can I use a Perl hash key that has a literal dot?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash in Perl which has been dumped into from some legacy code the name of the key has now changed from simply reqHdrs to reqHdrs.bla

```
$rec->{reqHdrs.bla}
```

My problem is now I cant seem to access this field from the hash any ideas?
The following is my error

```
Download Script Output: Bareword "reqHdrs" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

Comment: *`How can I use a Perl hash key that has a literal dot?`* -- The title is somewhat misleading: it's not the *literal dot* that makes the problem, but the unquoted *key literal* with a dot in it.

Answer (score 17):

As described in [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> ...An identifier within such curlies is forced to be a string, as is any simple identifier within a hash subscript.  Neither need quoting.  Our
>   earlier example, `$days{'Feb'}` can be written as `$days{Feb}` and the quotes will be assumed automatically.  But anything more complicated in the subscript
>   will be interpreted as an expression.  This means for example that `$version{2.0}++` is equivalent to `$version{2}++`, not to `$version{'2.0'}++`.

In general, if you have a hash key with a character outside the `[A-Za-z0-9_]` range, use quotes (either single or double) inside the braces. As with normal strings, contents in double quotes will be parsed for any contained variables, while single quoted strings are taken literally:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $x = 1;
my %hash = (
    bare_string => 'hi there',
    "not a bare string" => 'yup',
);
$hash{'$x'} = 'foo';
$hash{"$x"} = 'bar';
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'bare_string' => 'hi there',
      'not a bare string' => 'yup',
      '$x' => 'foo'
      '1' => 'bar',
    };
```

Comment: Upvote for the most comprehensive and helpful answer of the lot. :)

Answer (score 5):

According to `perldoc perldata` that when an identifier is used within curlies, such as when accessing a hash value via a key, that identifier is assumed to be a string and is treated as such. Quotes will be assumed automatically, however, anything more complicated can be interpreted.

From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

> In fact, an identifier within such
>   curlies is forced to be a string, as
>   is any simple identifier within a hash
>   subscript. Neither need quoting. Our
>   earlier example, `$days{'Feb'}`  can be
>   written as `$days{Feb}`  and the quotes
>   will be assumed automatically. But
>   anything more complicated in the
>   subscript will be interpreted as an
>   expression. This means for example
>   that `$version{2.0}++`  is equivalent to
>   `$version{2}++` , not to
>   `$version{'2.0'}++` .

Since the `.` is used for string concatenation, the interpreter I'm guessing is trying to concat those two strings together. Regardless it's always better to just use quotes to make it explicit, and if you have [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) on it will probably throw a "bareword not allowed" error.

The solution to your problem:

```
$rec->{'reqHdrs.bla'}
```

Comment: I did not see the previous post that quoted the same snippet from perldata.

Answer (score 4):

If the key is a string, just:

```
$rec->{"reqHdrs.bla"}
```

Comment: ...with a very tiny performance gain if you use a single-quoted ( `'` ) rather than a double quoted ( `"` ) string ;)

Comment: @Carl: why is a single quote faster?

Comment: @Eli: Single quotes don't interpolate.

Comment: @Michael, yes but can't that be easily optimized away by Perl for strings w/o interpolation variables?

Comment: The double quote allows you (always, not just in `print` statements) to use interpolated variables, e.g. `"foo$number"`. It's my understanding that a double-quoted string will force Perl to make a quick check for a variable buried in the string before going ahead and doing what it would have done with a plain single-quoted string.

Comment: @Eli: Judging by the output of `perl -MO=Terse`, it can. There's a school of thought that says you should use single-quotes where you can to provide a hint *to the programmer* that interpolation isn't necessary, though that can bite you if you ever add something requiring interpolation and forget to change the quotes.

Comment: @Carl: There is only one implementation of Perl. Perl 6 will have a formal specification, allowing multiple implementations. (e.g. Pugs and Rakudo)

Comment: @Carl the difference is zero, not tiny. Perl is not PHP, and the difference between single quotes and double quotes is resolved at compile time so that `"foo"` and `'foo'` generate identical code.

Comment: @hobbs and Michael Carman: Thanks for your clarifications. I retract my statement that single quotes are a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the key in quotes:

```
$rec->{'reqHdrs.bla'}
```

Answer (score -1):

The bareword `reqHdrs.bla` is really just a... synonym, I guess, for a string. I'm not completely sure, but I think you should be able to simply use a string, e.g. `'reqHdrs.bla'` as your key and that should retrieve your value OK.