# Perl accessing a hash within a hash and looping through each to extract the value

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to access a hash within a hash and loop through it to get the values. here is an example of the data

```
$VAR1 = {
      '24.40.53.143' => {
                          'ServStat' => {
                                          '1.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.98.112.109.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => 'vs_cgggbpm-ap_https',
                                          '1.17.118.115.95.99.119.98.115.102.97.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112' => 'vs_cddedsfa-ap_http',
                                          '20.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.116.119.98.45.98.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => '0',
                                          '19.17.118.115.95.99.119.98.119.115.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => '0',
                                          '2.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.116.119.98.45.98.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => '0',
                                          '24.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.116.119.98.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => '0',
                                          '17.17.118.115.95.99.119.98.119.98.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => '0',
                                          '29.17.118.115.95.99.119.98.116.119.112.45.98.112.95.104.116.116.112' => '0',
```

I would like to loop through 'ServStat' and extract each values. How would I reference the hash 'ServStat' so that I can do a foreach on the contents? Something like this:

```
foreach {ServStat} {
my ( $num, $char, $vs ) = (/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(.+)/ );
if ($num == 1) { 
print {ServStat}->$value
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advise you can offer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the keys, you can use the function [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) on the hash.

```
my $data = {
      '24.40.53.143' => {
                          'ServStat' => {'1.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.98.112.109.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115' => 'vs_cgggbpm-ap_https'}
      }
};


my $ServStat = $data->{24.40.53.143}{ServStat};

foreach my $key (keys %{$ServStat}) { # you need the {} to dereference as $ServStat is a hash reference
 ...#Now, in $key, you have the key 1.18.118.115.95.99.119.98.98.112.109.45.97.112.95.104.116.116.112.115

}
```

If you just want all values, just use the function [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) on the hash

```
my @values = values %{$ServStat};
```

Comment: You don't really need the {} unless the thing you're dereferencing contains indexes, e.g., keys %{$data->{24.40.53.143}{ServStat}};

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post a reply. Your solution was very helpful. I did have to use quotes around the hashes, like this:my $ServStat = $data->{'24.40.53.143'}{'ServStat'};  thanks again for the help!!

Comment: @dars - quotes are optional around "simple" strings (e.g. containing letters/numbers/underscores). So the first key (IP) needs to be quoted under `use strict;` whereas the second one doesn't - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647425/how-can-i-use-a-perl-hash-key-that-has-a-literal-dot . However, it's usually considered good practice to ALWAYS single quote even when not required - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401556/are-quotes-around-hash-keys-a-good-practice-in-perl